# setting variable from string in a file using sed and regex

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

**UPDATE** Edited the script slightly for a more specific regex, still same problem.

Clarifying following questions, this is my exact script I want to get working (POC for a bigger script), test.txt is in the same directory as my test.sh file and I'm running the script cd'ed in the same directory.

Also, whilst tinkering, I think this might be related to carriage returns, but I still can't figure out what's going wrong.

**END UPDATE**

I've looked around here to paste together a bash file I can run to extract a version number from a specific file, and do stuff with that version number via the variable. I have the rest of the script working if I just supply the version via an argument $1, but it'd be neat if it could just determine the version number directly from the file in the folder I want to manipulate.

Here's my current script

```
#!/bin/sh
version=$(sed -ne "s/\\Version *: *\([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]+\)*/\1/p" test.txt)
printf 'detected version %s for test.txt\n' "$version"
```

Which returns me this value in terminal

```
 for test.txtion 0.6
```

It seems to overwrite part of the string I'm trying to print. If I just take this part:

```
sed -ne "s/\\Version *: *\([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]+\)*/\1/p" test.txt
```

It works for example if there's a line in the file containing this line

```
Version: 0.6
```

I get this:

```
root@webserver [/home/username]# sed -ne "s/\\Version *: *\([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]+\)*/\1/p" test.txt
0.6
root@webserver [/home/username]#
```

Any ideas on what's wrong for the script?

Comment: Is it possible, that the file contains carriage returns (`\r`) in the "Version:..." line? I think the start of your output might be overwritten by the end. Try removing `for $file` to see, if the version number is printed.

Comment: Is that your actual code? if so, you are adding an additional suffix to the file name (`$file.php` when `file` is already assigned the value `filename.php`). Does the file `filename.php.php` exist?

Comment: You might want to use `grep` instead of `sed` ... And do not use variables in the FORMAT argument of `printf`. Use `printf 'detected version %s for %s\n' "$version" "$file"`

Comment: @eike it's very possible, I'm going to check that out and get back to you thanks

Comment: @steeldriver This isn't exactly my code, but the $file.php part is essentially the same just different variable names. I've removed that variable now for simplicity and used hard links, the issue I have is with the sed part really.

Comment: @pLumo I'd be ok with grep too, but I'm not very good with bash, so a suggestion on how to do that would be helpful :) thanks for the printf suggestion but it doesn't help, I'll update the OP though

Comment: @steeldriver I should add, while toying around with the sed part I got an error that did show the 0.6 in the error message, so it is getting the right file, just the output I can't figure out.

Comment: I don't think this helps, but your backreference `\1` is empty. To match the non-space characters inside the brackets, you have to escape the `+` and to match any following characters you need `.*` (if you want `\1` to contain a value). Something like `sed -ne 's/.*Version: *\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p'`. Also, I don't understand why there is a ```\\``` at the start of the regex.

Comment: @Freddy, I'm not sure why either, I took that from another StackExchange question with a similar question and adapted that. I'm used to PHP-style regex. What's odd is that it works if entered straight into the terminal, just not when assigning as a variable.

Your suggestions gives me:

>  for events-manager-io1

Comment: @marcus Is this script really the whole script you're using or just a part of it? I have the feeling the bug is somewhere else. Also, you're using `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`. It doesn't make a difference for the script you posted, but it could make a difference for a bigger bash script.

Comment: What is your /bin/sh? Is it a link to bash? This works fine here (where /bin/sh is indeed a symlink to bash), so it has to be something in your environment that's causing this.

Comment: @Freddy The above is the exact script I'm using to test. I think it's related to carriage returns though, I'm going to update my OP slightly to reflect my current tinkering.

Comment: @NickD I'm not well versed in Linux/Unix, I assume it is a link to bash. What do you want me to look at to give more info?

Comment: @NickD changing bin/sh to bin/bash on the script has no effect. I'm at the point of giving up and just doing it in PHP

Comment: I hope you do not abandon the effort: the script is fine, so It would be interesting to find out what's causing the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is related to \r in the txt file. I can't do much about that, but I also don't know why the ( ) is including that \r because it's only meant to catch numbers, letters, dots and hyphens.

If anyone else can recommend a grep equivalent, any method will work if I can just extract that version number into a variable :) I can do it with PHP but I'd love to see this one through in a language more challenging for me!

Comment: @NickD, thanks for the motivational push... I tried one last-ditch attempt and figured out a way...

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason this wasn't working, and also the solution. As @eike commented in my OP, the issue was the carriage return \r from DOS overwriting the output. More problematically for me, the \r got added to my variable for some reason.

Removing the \r manually wasn't an option because that file gets updated regularly.

After a bit of searching, I found this to fix my problem and print out the string correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
version=$(sed 's/\r$//' test.txt | sed -ne "s/\\Version *: *\([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]+\)*/\1/p")
printf 'detected version %s for test.txt\n' "$version"
```

What it does here is first remove the \r from the text and pass that to the regex part. and I get the expected output:

> detected version 0.6 for test.txt

I'm sure there's a way to do it from within the regex, to ignore the \r, but this got the job done at least!

Comment: I still cannot get it to fail even with a file with DOS line endings. I think there is a bug in your regexp however: the `+` is supposed to match a literal plus sign if you are not using extended regexps; the 'match one or more instances of the previous match' is denoted `\+` - assuming you are using [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE) that is. And I'm not at all sure about what the final `*` is supposed to be doing: `sed -ne "s/Version *: *\([0-9a-zA-Z\.\-]\+\)/\1/p" test.txt` works fine for me.

Comment: I must be using GNU sed because the + doesn't work when escaped (I tried). Also, if it was a literal plus I wouldn't be getting the output I get since it did find the number (and there's no pluses in the string). 

I did find the last * odd, it's part of a regex example I picked up in another stack overflow thread.

It's 100% the \r though, I don't know why, but the solution fixed all my problems so I am happy to leave it at that :) Thanks for your input @NickD